# Azure Cosmos Db Unique Composite Key Constraints

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When defining the unique key, what is the difference between /address/zipcode vs /address, /zipcode

Answer (score 2):

- `/address` + `/zipcode` = composite unique key, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys) for more details.
- `/address/zipcode` is a single unique key for this, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#include-exclude-paths) for more details.

```
 {
        "address": { "zipcode": "xxxx"}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer, hence posting here:

/address/zipcode translates into an object reference as address.zipcode where as /address and /zipcode are two fields